# What is the difference between assertions in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

What is the difference between:

- `cy.contains('text').should('be.visible')`; and
- `cy.should('be.visible','text')`?

Because for me the first option is working to check the text but the second it doesn't check properly, so  I was wondering in which cases I can use the second option for checking the text?

Comment: According to documentation [1], you can't use the second case once `should` can't be chained directly from `cy`. Are you sure your example is correct?


  [1]: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Usage

Comment: I aslo had hesitations with the second option, but then I saw it in this exapmle and i thought it should work, but apperently it doesn't work like this. SO i thought maybe somewhere else i can use it, so i decided to know the diference. I saw it here https://medium.com/slido-dev-blog/cypress-tips-4-testing-lists-of-items-dccd4b688816
 thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cy.should()
```

doesn't exist, you need to yield something before you run an assertion on it. You can read more about the command [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html).

The syntax mentioned in the documentation:

> .should(chainers)

it does not start with `cy.`, so it means you have to have another command that yields something before you use `.should()`.

You can compare it to what documentation mentions for [`cy.get()` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Syntax) that could be directly chained with `cy`:

> cy.get(selector)

Answer (score 0):

If you read this article https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Usage , it's an incorrect usage of using cy.should(). So, it's better not to use second option.